# Чтение и вывод информации из 100 файлов

Tags: php, файлы, строки

Свой вариант, вопрос остался:

```
$dir = "./radio/radio_stantion/";
$name = scandir($dir);
for($i=2; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {

$fopen=file( $dir.$name[$i] );
$line = $fopen[3];
$url = $fopen[2];
$radio_name = explode(") ", $line);
$radio_url = explode("//", $url);
$link = $radio_url[1];
$http = explode(":", $link);
$fff = $http[1];
$port = explode("/", $fff); 

echo $radio_name[1]."<br/>";
echo $http[0]."<br/>";
echo $port[0]."<br/>";
}
```

Выводится: 
`FRESH 105.9 FM IBADAN 
s4.voscast.com 
8442 
Bestfriend FM 
178.32.62.172 
8217 
SmoothJazz 
149.56.155.209
80 
и тд из 100 файлов...`

Вопрос остался: Как теперь взять по отдельности

```
Block1: $ radio_name1(FRESH 105.9 FM IBADAN), $ http1(s4.voscast.com), $ port1(8442);
Block2: $ radio_name2(Bestfriend FM), $ http2(178.32.62.172 ), $ port2(8217);
Block3: $ radio_name3(SmoothJazz), $ http3(149.56.155.209), $ port3(80 ).
```

?

Comment: Очистьте и обновите свой вопрос указав во первых как выглядит ваш txt файл.Помните что функция `file()` разбирает филе в массив построчно.То есть `$fopen[0]` будет равна строке `1.txt name: $radio_name_1[1], host: $http_1[0],  port: $port_1[0]`.Учитывая это постарайтесь еще облегчить код Описав более конкретную задачу

Comment: Есть список. Как взять все по отдельности?

Comment: Приведите пример списка.Как он выглядит ,какие там данные ?

Comment: Вверху вывод. Нужно:`Block1: $ radio_name1(FRESH 105.9 FM IBADAN), $ http1(s4.voscast.com), $ port1(8442);Block2: $ radio_name2(Bestfriend FM), $ http2(178.32.62.172 ), $ port2(8217);Block3: $ radio_name3(SmoothJazz), $ http3(149.56.155.209), $ port3(80 )`.... Присвоить переменные, чтобы можно было далее использовать не списком, а по отдельности.

Comment: А возможно изменить структуру строк ?Типо этого   `radio_name1=FRESH 105.9 FM IBADAN, http1=s4.voscast.com, port1=8442`

Comment: Возможно. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можешь к примеру с помощью регулярного выражения получить все эти файлы, а потом обработать их в цикле.

```
$NAME_PATTERN = '!\.(txt)$!i';
$MAIN_DIR = './radio/radio_stantion/';
$arFiles = Array();
$mainDirFiles = scandir($MAIN_DIR);
foreach ($mainDirFiles as $file)
{
  if (preg_match($NAME_PATTERN, $file))
  {
    $arFiles[] = $MAIN_DIR.$file;

    //можно обработать прямо в цикле
    $fopen=file( $file );
    $line = $fopen[3];
    $url = $fopen[2];
    $radio_name = explode(") ", $line);
    $radio_url = explode("//", $url);
    $link = $radio_url[1];
    $http = explode(":", $link);
    $fff = $http[1];
    $port = explode("/", $fff); 

    echo 'file: ' . $file;
    echo 'name:' . $radio_name[1];
    echo 'host:' . $http[0];
    echo 'port:' . $port[0];
  }
}
```

Теперь в `$arFiles` массив с именами всех файлов txt в данной папке, можешь перебрать их в цикле. Или же прям в цикле с регулярным выражением как в примере выше.

Comment: Зачем `array_push` если можно просто написать  `$arFiles[] = $MAIN_DIR.$file` ?

Comment: Просто забыл поправить, брал из пример брал из своего кода, а там я добавлял в цикле в массив сразу два элемента, эти методы конечно аналогичны, но  `$arFiles[]` конечно же лучше выглядит.

Comment: У меня не работает. Написал свой вариант. Выводится список `FRESH 105.9 FM IBADAN 
s4.voscast.com
8442 
Bestfriend FM 
178.32.62.172
8217 и тд` Как теперь взять по отдельности name, host,port?

Comment: @Sergey_777 Пробуй ,как не получится токо задавай вопрос. Ну во первых покажите как выглядеть ваш `txt` файл с данными ?

Comment: @Sergey_777 `1.txt name: $radio_name_1[1], host: $http_1[0],  port: $port_1[0]` Если так то это строка,надо и ее разбить на части по определенной логике,чтоб получить левую часть `name,host...` и их значения